# How to stop nextjs holding previously scrolled position of shared component?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

In brands page I scrolled to the bottom of page. Stay in touch is shared component of all routes.

When I again click on link of get in touch, page is showing at the bottom of page where shared component stay in touch is there.

I want every time page to be at top. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

below is code of stay in touch component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from "jquery";
import {event} from "next/dist/build/output/log";
import {submitContactUsData} from "../../pages/api/contactus";
import {notification} from "antd";

export default class StayInTouch extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
            email:"",
            emailValid:false,
            formSubmitted:false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        gsap.to(".topAnchor", {
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: ".wrapper",
                start: "top top",
                scrub: 0.2,
                end: "bottom",
                pinnedContainer: ".wrapper",
                pin: false,
            },
            rotation: 360 * 5,
            ease: "none",
        });

        $(".topAnchor").click(() => {
            // console.log('clicked');
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            // gsap.to(window, { duration: 2, scrollTo: 0 });
        });

        // Cursor 3 end

        $(".liv_off").click(() => {
            $(".liv_off").removeClass("active");
            $(".liv_on").addClass("active");
        });
        $(".liv_on").click(() => {
            $(".liv_on").removeClass("active");
            $(".liv_off").addClass("active");
        });


    }
    openNotificationWithIcon=(type,message,desc)=>{
        notification[type]({
            message: message,
            description:desc,
            top:70
        });
    }

    handleChange=(e)=>{
        this.setState({email:e.target.value});
        this.setState({emailValid:this.validateEmail(e.target.value)})
    }

    validateEmail=(email)=>{
        const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }

    submitFormData=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        debugger;
        if(this.state.emailValid){
            let contactUsData={
                name:"Guest",
                email:this.state.email,
                message:"Stay in touch",
                contactNumber:'-',
                user:'minoanexperience.com'
            }

            submitContactUsData(contactUsData).then(data=>{
                this.openNotificationWithIcon('success',"Submitted successfully.",'')
                this.setState({
                    email: "",
                    emailValid:false,
                    formSubmitted:true
                })
            },err=>{
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <footer className="footer_main">
                <div className="container mw_1440">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-10 mb-3">
                                    <div className="footer_left d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                                        {
                                            !this.state.formSubmitted&&(
                                                <form onSubmit={this.submitFormData} className={'w-100'}>

                                                    <div className="input-group input_group_footer">
                                                        <input type="text" className="form-control custom_input_transparent"
                                                               placeholder="Your email" aria-label="Stay in touch" value={this.state.email}
                                                               aria-describedby="button-addon2" id="forEmail" onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete={'off'}/>
                                                        <label className="ip_footer ip_stay" htmlFor="">Stay in touch</label>
                                                        <label className="ip_footer ip_email" htmlFor="forEmail">Your email</label>
                                                        {
                                                            this.state.emailValid&&(
                                                                <button className="btn btn_submit_1 align-self-center" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Submit <span
                                                                    className="circle_ui circleActive"></span></button>
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                        {
                                                            !this.state.emailValid&&(
                                                                <button className="btn btn_submit_1 align-self-center" type="button" id="button-addon2"  disabled>Submit <span
                                                                    className="circle_ui"></span></button>

                                                            )
                                                        }

                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            )
                                        }
                                        {
                                            this.state.formSubmitted&&(
                                                <div className={'d-flex w-100 mb-3'}>
                                                    <label className="d-flex w-100 success_message">You’re all done!</label>
                                                    <button className="btn btn_submit_success" type="button" id="button-addon2">Thanks!</button>
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        }

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <div className="footer_right">
                                <div className="fr_upper">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-6 align-self-center">
                                            <p className="heading_footer_1">Follow along:</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-6 align-self-center">
                                            <ul className="social_links">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a className="heading_footer_1" rel={'noreferrer'} target={'_blank'} href="https://www.instagram.com/minoanexperience/">
                                                        <img src="assets/images/socialIcons_ig_icon_24px_02.svg" alt=""/>

                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a className="heading_footer_1" rel={'noreferrer'} target={'_blank'} href="https://www.facebook.com/minoanexperience">
                                                        <img src="assets/images/socialIcons_fb_icon_24px_02.svg" alt=""/>

                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a className="heading_footer_1" rel={'noreferrer'} target={'_blank'} href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/minoan">
                                                        <img src="assets/images/socialIcons_in_icon_24px_02.svg" alt=""/>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="min_living">
                                    <img
                                        className="minoan_living_img liv_off active"
                                        src="assets/images/Minoan_Living_Off.svg"
                                        alt="living_space"
                                    />
                                    <img
                                        className="minoan_living_img liv_on"
                                        src="assets/images/Minoan_Living_On.svg"
                                        alt="living_space"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6 align-self-end">
                            <div className="footer_logo">
                                <img src="assets/images/minoan_logo.svg" alt="logo"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6 align-self-end">
                            <div className="d-flex">
                                {/*<a className="me-auto link_footer_1" href="javascript:void(0);">*/}
                                {/*    © Minoan Experience, Inc. 2021*/}
                                {/*</a>*/}

                                <ul className={'links_footer_bottom'}>
                                    <li>
                                        <a className={"link_footer_1"}  href="javascript:void(0)">© Minoan Experience, Inc. 2021</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a className={"link_footer_1"}  rel={'noreferrer'} target={'_blank'} href="https://www.minoanexperience.com/terms">Terms & Conditions</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a className={"link_footer_1"}  rel={'noreferrer'} target={'_blank'} href="https://www.minoanexperience.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
                {/* To Top */}
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" className="topAnchor">
                    <img src="assets/images/top.svg" alt="to_top" />
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this in the main app.js file:

```
componentDidMount() {
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
        window.scroll({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: tried above facing same issue

Comment: is there any error shown?

Comment: No error it doesn't make any difference still have same issue only